# How maven know which archetype is used?

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I am wonder how maven know which archetype is used for specified pom.xml

I didn't find any difference between pom.xml of maven-archetype-quickstart and that of maven-archetype-webapp.

Comment: Did you find a way to know which archetype is used for a maven project?

Comment: What are the benefits of knowing the archetype of the maven project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two different Questions:

> I am wonder how maven know which
>   archetype is used for specified
>   pom.xml

The archetype plugin is usually used interactively. You just call `mvn archetype:create`, and the wizard walks you through the different steps. There's nothing you need to configure in a pom. In fact it would be silly to put archetype information in an existing project, as archetypes are for creating new projects.

> I did not found any difference between
>   pom.xml of maven-archetype-quickstart
>   and that of maven-archetype-webapp.

The main difference is that webapp contains a folder src/main/webapp which contains your static web resources and the WEB-INF folder. Also, the packaging is set to `war`. So `maven-archetype-quickstart` is the default for creating a simple jar project, while `maven-archetype-webapp` is the default for creating a simple war project.

Comment: Where can we find a detailed definition/description for each maven archetype? Such as its intended usage.

Comment: @smwikipedia you can't. there is no such central service, which is exactly what's wrong with archetypes

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So this lack of description is the weak point of the archetype design?

Comment: Think of an archetype as a template. You can start with one but after that it has no bearing on how you change it. Personally the only time I have used archetype is for teaching to get newbies started. In the real world you just copy paste a pom and edit it as necessary.

Comment: @smwikipedia To provide an updated answer your very old question on archetypes provided by Maven, there is excellent documentation on the eleven archetypes provided by Maven (i.e. those with names of the form _maven-archetype-{xxx}_) [on Maven's web site](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/index.html).